# Declare variable outside any class: why is it possible

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a file `fancy_button.dart` for a custom Flutter widget `FancyButton` which is like:

```dart
class FancyButton extends StatefulWidget {
    // ...
}

class _FancyButtonState extends State<FancyButton> {
    // ...
}

// Declaration outside any class:

Map<_FancyButtonState, Color> _buttonColors = {};

final _random = Random();

int next(int min, int max) => min + _random.nextInt(max - min);

// ...
```

The application works just fine. Notice that I declare and use some variables outside any class. Now my question is: how is it even possible? Shouldn't everything be inside a class in Dart, like Java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, Dart supports variables and functions defined in global space. You can see this with the `main()` method which are declared outside any class.

Also, global variables (and static class variables) are lazy evaluated so the value are first defined when you are trying to use them. So your runtime are not going to slow down even if there are a bunch of global variables there are not used.

Comment: The way you put it, it sounds like it's actually a good thing to use global variables then?

Comment: @Aegletes I have a Java background so I am not really fan of using global variables. This lazy load behavior is also valid for static variables in classes which is what I do most of the time.

Comment: yeah I can imagine that calms down the java dev inside you, but it's good to know, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you coming from Java before touching Dart?

Basically, Dart is not single-class-single-file like how Java works. Yes, it does support Object Oriented Programming (in kinda different way). The behavior of constructor is different. There is no `public`, `private`, and `protected` keywords. Please just refer to the official docs.

Anyway, you don't need a complex `public static void main()`. The real entry point is `main()`. Unless you define that function, you won't be able to run a file in command line.

Comment: "But basically the program will be run from top, down to bottom." is not correct. The program starts with the `main()` method and global variables are defined in the order they are used.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Mismatched with python scripting (while replying this).